# What's the meaning of "First one dies, you die too"?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun

Right after the scene where Goose hits the jettisoned aircraft canopy head-first and is killed,
Maverick is shown washing his face and Viper meets him:

> Viper: You fly jets long enough, something like this happens.
>
> Maverick: He was my RIO, my responsibility.
>
> Viper: In my squadron in Vietnam, we lost eight of 18 aircraft. Ten
> men. **First one dies, you die too**. But there will be others. You
> can count on it.

What's the meaning of "First one dies, you die too" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not meant literally.  "First one dies, you die too" refers to the devastating effect on one's morale on losing troops for whom one bears responsibility.